# How to open PayPal checkout with opened "Pay with a credit or debit card" tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is there a way to open PayPal checkout with opened "Pay with a credit or debit card" tab though adaptive payments api?

What determines tab that will be opened in checkout page?

Answer (score 1):

With Adaptive Payments you can't control that.  PayPal determines what tabs are opened by default.

If you use Express Checkout you can force the "guest checkout" experience, so that the credit card option (without signing in) is prominently displayed by default.

Express Checkout only supports parallel payments, though, not chained.  So, depending on what you're doing with Adaptive Payments you may or may not be stuck.